# How to increase stack space of CPP in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, stack-overflow

I was working on some problem of Facebook Hackercup and it actually involved implementation of Segment Tree 
I used a recursive version of Segment Tree which caused Stack Overflow on A Big TEST CASE FILE 
I was using Sublime Text as my editor, I just received a runtime error 
But When I approached the same problem with an Iterative Implementation of Segment Trees It got an AC without problems.

The issue is I want to increase Stack Space of CPP in my Windows 10 , using Dev CPP or Sublime Text editor , Can somebody help me with that?

I surfed a little and All I got was that the stack space in CPP is only 8 mb but for Linux systems we can go upto one GB of stack space 
[COMMAND FOR INCREASING STACK SPACE IN LINUX](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/63140) 
, I want to do it for windows.

UPD => Or is there any way to do it for Ubuntu System ??

Comment: Broadly speaking, if you need to increase the stack space your program uses because of how you implemented your code, your real problem is not the limited stack space, but instead is your *implementation* that needs more stack space. *Especially* if you can get an iterative solution to work.

Comment: If you're running out of stack space the first thing you do is figure out why, not beg for more stack space. Maybe you should use things like `std::vector` instead of a stack-based array, for example.

Comment: Umm ! But On Linux OS (which has a feature to change your stack space of cpp) the recursive  versions works just fine, I can share the link of source if you wish?

Comment: The linker is responsible for setting the stack size. Though it's questionable whether your local environment has any effect on the (presumably independent) verification system.

Comment: @tadman  May I share my code because I was using std::vector<int> only ,It took a lot of recursion stack space which caused troubles?

Comment: It's always helpful to include a small, representative example of what you're doing. Edit your question to include that.

Comment: the only sure method is to make recursion's footprint size to be zero or limit amount of iterations. Platform have different limitations

Comment: @IInspectable I surfed a lot ! But all I got was a command which can do Almost 1 gb Stack space for Linux systems Meanwhile in windows it is limited to 8mb only :(

Comment: Have you tried to add the /STACK linker command? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/stack?view=vs-2019

Comment: I didn't get how to use it @Raildex ! It is not very well explained that what steps should I follow

Comment: Maybe you just need to accept the fact that if you cannot control the recursion depth, you cannot use a recursive algorithm. Trying to postpone failure indefinitely is an exercise in futility.

Comment: @IInspectable It is  not that I can't write Iterative codes I can equally do it I just want if such a features exists in Linux So will it in Windows I am curious about the way to do it

Comment: If you need more stack space, you could perform the recursion in a separate worker thread.  Functions like [`CreateThread()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createthread) on Windows, [`pthread_create()`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) on Linux, etc have input parameters to specify the thread's stack size, which can be different than the default stack size specified in the EXE by the linker.

Comment: @RemyLebeau  Can you please some link related to it ?  where i can find some tutorial to use it

Comment: @KnightKnight start with the links in my previous comment. Writing multi-threaded code is not trivial, and way too broad to cover in comments.  There are plenty of books and tutorials on the subject

Comment: OK I will refer those Links :) :) Thankks for the help  , But Please don;t close the question for now maybe someone else has a way to do it so some cmd command which can help me

Comment: 1) *CPP* has nothing to do with stack-space 2) Stack space is limited not arbitrarily, but for *good reasons* - akin , loosely, to how one does not simply "ask windows" for *more* L1 cache

Comment: cpp has nothing to do with stack space really ? I can provide some links which show that stack space is 8mb for by gcc compiler